# Facebook: Can I Programmatically Add a Friend?

Tags: api, facebook

Is there a Facebook API to add a friend? I can't find one, but then I can't find it stated anywhere that there isn't one, and this seems like something a lot of people would be asking about.

(Note: I'm not talking about a Facebook application, but rather an HTTP-based API.)

**Clarification**

I should mention that I'm trying to do this WITH the users authorization. They give me their username and password. Not trying to spam anyone.

Twitter has a very simple API for doing this; I'd hoped Facebook did too.

Comment: Sorry to butt in on your serious inquiry, but I can't help smiling a little at the question "Can I Programmatically Add a Friend?"... :)

Answer (score 4):

I do not think there is a way to do this. This is based on user's choice. The best bet would be to have the user pushed to the profile in question and have them do the work.

**Edit:**
You should **never** ask for a username and password for facebook. that is a violation of the terms of facebook and a poor design choice. you should use their standard api for accessing data to/from facebook.

Comment: That seems likely - my impression is that Facebook is very careful not to let things be done programmatically on behalf of their users, without explicit authorization.

Comment: +1, yeah, yeah, I'm guessing that this would be a security hole. But, then again, there's probably a way to fake it if you were really persistent. (It would also be likely some violation of the usage terms of the site)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I AM trying to use their standard API. I would like to add a friend, with their permission. If such an API call exists, it would surely require their name and password, right?

Answer (score 2):

I spent a great deal of time looking, and finally came accross a very simple solution.

Using the Facebook Javascript API you can do a friend request with:

```
<script>
    FB.ui(
     { 
      method: 'friends.add', 
      id: fbid // assuming you set this variable previously...
     }, 
     function(param){

      console.log(param);

            // If they cancel params will show: 
            //    {action:false, ...}
            // and if they send the friend request it'll have:
            //    {action:true, ...}
            // and if they closed the pop-up window then:
            //    param is undefined
     }
    );
</script>
```

The callback script can then simply performs an ajax call to your server where 
you save info about the action, if needed.

You can test this by using the javascript console app on Facebook:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/console

Paste in the script above, including the  tags, or click the "Examples"
button on the bottom of the text area and find the "fb.ui — friends.add" example.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [SimpleTest's scriptable browser](http://www.lastcraft.com/browser_documentation.php).  It is part of their test framework, but you can use the browser component independently.

[Snoopy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snoopy/) is another good option.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think we shouldn't ask for user Pass and User name.

But, If you need to do it in your application you can use database/XML to do that. But only your application will treat the added user as a friend not the facebook.

In my application i added all friends in DB and also added my self as a friend of my self. so that i can do the task what is defined to myFriends role(in my application).

ID        FBUserId         Name

9705    1215966620  Abul Bashar
9706    1248090545  Tuhin Ahmed
9707    1251036547  Orijit Diponkor Shuvrangshu Tridib
9708    1252800907  Shahin Mahmud
9709    1263680515  Binayan Dey
9710    1275860308  Mitu Kumar Debnath
9711    1279017492  Ahmed Riaj
9712    1280150772  Mahbubur Rub Talha
9713    1287414234  প্রবাসী সারোয়ার
9714    1294159220  Md.Humayun Kabir
9715    1294340379  Shah Muhammad Mazed