# Is it possible to launch friend request via facebook graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want to launch friend requests via the facebook graph API, is it possible ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to send friend request on facebook using koala gem?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9940355/how-to-send-friend-request-on-facebook-using-koala-gem)

Answer (score -1):

type "Facebook Graph API" into Google and you will find this link:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/

with this description:

**Create**

> You can invite users to an event by issuing an HTTP POST to
>   /EVENT_ID/invited/USER_ID. You can invite multiple users by issuing an
>   HTTP POST to /EVENT_ID/invited?users=USER_ID1,USER_ID2,USER_ID3. Both
>   of these require the create_event permission and return true if the
>   invite is successful.

**Read**

You can read the list of invitees for an event by issuing an HTTP GET to /EVENT_ID/invited:

https://graph.facebook.com/331218348435/invited

You can check whether a specific user has been invited to an event by issuing an HTTP GET to /EVENT_ID/invited/USER_ID:

https://graph.facebook.com/331218348435/invited/2503747

You'll need the user_events or friend_events permissions to view the invite list for for non-public events.

These calls return an object with the name, id, and rsvp_status ('not_replied', 'unsure', 'attending', or 'declined') fields. When checking for a specific user, if the user is not invited to the event, the API will return an empty data array.

**Delete**

You can un-invite a user from an event by issuing an HTTP DELETE to /EVENT_ID/invited/USER_ID. Returns true if the request is successful. The user must be an admin (i.e. creator) of the event for this call to succeed. Requires rsvp_event permission.

Comment: I'm almost sure he was asking about friend requests, hence my duplicate tagging

Comment: As Igy says it was about friend invitations and not event invitations

Comment: ups, sorry. Maybe this will work, but its from 2009 and coulb be deprecated: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4403940/1152471